# Usage of BiConsumer interface in java 8

Tags: java, java-8, functional-interface

I'm new to programming with streams and functional interfaces and the `java.util.function.BiConsumer` describes the method `accept` like below in the documentation which is not clear to understand

```
void accept(T t,
            U u)
Performs this operation on the given arguments.
Parameters:
t - the first input argument
u - the second input argument
```

Functional interfaces can be referred using the lamda expressions like below

```
BiConsumer<String,String> a=(a,b)->{
 
}
```

But what does the "this operation mean here exactly". Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that a `BiConsumer` represents an "operation" that takes 2 parameters.

For example, if you have

```
BiConsumer<String,String> foo = (a, b) -> System.out.println(a + b);
```

`foo` represents the operation `System.out.println(a + b);` - printing the two parameters concatenated together.

"This operation" just means the operation that the `BiConsumer` instance represents.

So in the example above, "this operation" for `foo` just means "`System.out.println(a + b);`".

The documentation is saying that if you call `accept`, the operation represented by the instance (for `foo`, it is `System.out.println(a + b);`) will be performed.

Answer (score 5):

> But what does the "this operation" mean here exactly?

The `BiConsumer` interface is effectively a signature for any function that takes two arguments of two reference types (or in your example, the same type) and returns nothing.  A function that conforms to this interface *could* do anything with them.  It could print them.  It could add them to some map.  It could ... throw them away, and do absolutely nothing.

The "this operation" refers to the lambda that (in effect) implements the interface.  Or more precisely, what the lambda *does*.

So ... basically ... when you pass (say) a lambda as an argument of type `BiConsumer` to some method, that method can call `accept(arg1, arg2)` and *expect* that it will do what that javadoc says; i.e. apply "the operation" implemented by the lambda (or whatever) to those two arguments.

Now the `BiConsumer` interface is a bit unusual because it doesn't return anything.  So it is not as widely used as other functional interfaces.  But if you are looking for examples, try this:

- [Java 8 BiConsumer Examples](https://mkyong.com/java8/java-8-biconsumer-examples/)

Answer (score 1):

To add on top of above scenario mentioned,there is one more in-built usage of BiConsumer:

**ForEach** default method of **map**

which got introduced in Java-8